# Wrong Quiz result

Tags: java, if-statement

[This](http://prntscr.com/8vx7o9) is the output of the program

I was able to do till to get [this result](http://prntscr.com/8vx85n) by doing this program below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aLittleQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declaring varibles

        String quizStart;
        int quizAns1, quizAns2, quizAns3;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz? (y / n)");
        quizStart = input.next();

        System.out.println("Okay, here it comes!");

        // quiz answer 1

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the capital of Alaska? \n1) Melbourne\n2) Anchorage\n3) Juneau");
        quizAns1 = input.nextInt();

        if (quizAns1 == 3) {
            System.out.println("That's right");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong, sorry!");
        }

        // quiz answer 2

        System.out.println("Q2) Can you store the value ''cat'' in a variable of type int? \n1) yes \n2) no");
        quizAns2 = input.nextInt();

        if (quizAns2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, ''cat'' is a string. ints can only store numbers.");
        } else if (quizAns2 == 2) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }

        // quiz answer 3

        System.out.println("What is the result of 9+6/3? \n1) 5\n2) 11 \n3) 15/3");
        quizAns3 = input.nextInt();
        if (quizAns3 == 2) {
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }

        // if (quizAns == 3 && quizAns == ) {

        // }

    }

}
```

but how I can program this part?

> "Overall, you got 2 out of 3 correct.
>   Thanks for playing!"

Comment: People having the right expertise should know they can probably help you before visiting other websites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a variable like `int marks` and increment it by one inside  `if\else` block(which made for correct answer). And at the end print

`System.out.println("Overall, you got" +marks+" out of 3 correct. Thanks for playing!");`

Assuming your no of question is fixed( 3 )

```
        String quizStart;
        int quizAns1, quizAns2, quizAns3;
        int marks=0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Are you ready for a quiz? (y / n)");
        quizStart = input.next();

        System.out.println("Okay, here it comes!");

        // quiz answer 1

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the capital of Alaska? \n1) Melbourne\n2) Anchorage\n3) Juneau");
        quizAns1 = input.nextInt();

        if (quizAns1 == 3) {
            System.out.println("That's right");
            ++marks;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your answer is wrong, sorry!");
        }

        // quiz answer 2

        System.out.println("Q2) Can you store the value ''cat'' in a variable of type int? \n1) yes \n2) no");
        quizAns2 = input.nextInt();

        if (quizAns2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, ''cat'' is a string. ints can only store numbers.");
        } else if (quizAns2 == 2) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            ++marks;
        }

        // quiz answer 3

        System.out.println("What is the result of 9+6/3? \n1) 5\n2) 11 \n3) 15/3");
        quizAns3 = input.nextInt();
        if (quizAns3 == 2) {
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
            ++marks;
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("Overall, you got " +marks+" out of 3 correct. Thanks for playing!");
```

Comment: Dont you think you should put a comment after giving a downvote ??Other  wise how would i correct my answer?

Comment: You should not have needed @Rehman to have rewritten your entire code base. The original description was perfectly clear as to what was needed to be done. Looking at the code now, it takes more effort to figure out what was changed.